# Where would the potential energy differential go if one were to teleport to a different height?

Tags: gravity, potential

If teleportation were to be somehow invented in the classic movie scenario (basically, enter a "magic portal" that immediately moves you to a different point in space). Ignoring some obvious problems (like the difference in local speeds between the entrance and exit "portals", one could wonder what would happen if one were to teleport from, say, the 10th floor of a building to the first floor of the same building.
Clearly, by "teleporting" from the 10th to the first floor the subjects gravitational potential energy has decreased, but it hasn't transformed into the usual kinetic energy to compensate (like when one walks or jumps down).

Is there any obvious form of energy to which this differential would transform, or is this yet another way in which teleportation is an unreasonable concept in our universe?

Comment: Interesting question. Quantum mechanically we just need the expectation value of energy to be conserved. We can measure an electron at a particular place and a moment later, there's a finite probability of measuring it someplace else. So in a sense, this is teleportation. Let's see if someone more knowledgeable answers it

Comment: Voting to close. We can't answer this in a reasonable way. If by teleport you mean travel get A to B without traveling there, you are not talking about physics. You can't do it. The universe doesn't work that way. If you pretend you can and ask about the energy, the answer is whatever you pretend. Dr. jh's answer is not correct. The potential energy difference is equal to the work done while traveling.

Comment: This is about science fiction, not main stream physics.

Answer (score 1):

That is the problem with teleportation: it can't work for that and other reasons.

Comment: In my modest opinion if a teleporter  would be invented it would care of it. At the end refrigerators are things. But I also say this Q isn't really about physics.

Answer (score 1):

If you could make the guy disappear at the 10th floor and reappear at the 1st floor, and if the law of conservation of energy where to *always* hold (and there is no reason to think that it wouldn't), then once he reappears at the first floor, he would have to be moving with a velocity $\sqrt {2gy}$ where $y$ would be the difference in height between the 10th and 1st levels. Please do not ask what happens if he was to be teleported from the 1st to the 10th floor, cause then he would have to emerge with a negative kinetic energy! :)

Comment: Good point, the reverse case, in which he teleports from the 1st to 10th floor, is even more odd/impossible. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B19nlhbA7-E